# Why Angular HTTP sends no body in POST request?

Tags: angular, angular5

This is method that sends request to server:

```
public Get(body: IGetPassportInfoRequest): Observable<IGetPassportInfoResponse> {

    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    });

    let options = {
      headers: httpHeaders
    };

    return this.http.post('http://ip:9090/terminal/get', body, options)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Where body is object:

```
 const data: IGetPassportInfoRequest = {
      doc_serie: this.step1.controls['passport_seria'].value,
      doc_number: this.step1.controls['passport_number'].value
    };
```

In chrome network I see:

[image]

Comment: Whats the response http code?

Comment: It sends OPTION request instead POST, why?: `Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed`

Comment: Have you enabled CORS on server?

Comment: cross domain requests are always pre-flighted by an OPTION request, you need to enable cors on your server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you got here is a CORS related error.
The server that you are trying to send data to needs to:

1. have appropriate CORS headers set
2. allow an OPTION method to be handled (CORS requests are always pre-flighted with OPTION request)

Readmore: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Should I configure client or server?

Comment: Server. Depending on the type of software you are using there might be ready-made packages for your needs, or you'll need to manually set appropriate headers (usually you'll need `allow-headers`, `allow-methods` and `allow-origin`).
As for the OPTION method, this can be the simplest route (i.e. return a blank page if the request method is OPTION).

Comment: Okay, then why does Postman work from local machine and gives correct response

Comment: Because it's not a cross-origin request (page requesting another page), but rather a direct request from your browser to the target (just as if you would open the page in brower)

Comment: Do you mean that postman sends request to server postman then to remote address? not directly from local?

Comment: Postman utilises your browser to send the request directly to target server. (so it's not a cross-origin request)